# stack/ladder n- mosfets

Tags: mosfet-driver, high-current, batteries, bms

I need to drive n-mosfets to switch on/off resistors in parallel with Lion cells.
Each cell+mosfet is in a series - 50 cells.

It looks much like a BMS except it NOT a BMS, but a cell test system. See the "idea" schematic of each single cell below.
Cells will be charged (M2 off, M1 on) powered from 40A current source. As cells reach nominal voltage, they are "taken out" of circuit by switching M2 on and M1 off.
Then they will be discharged, taken out of circuit when low voltage reached.

Cells will necessarily be (hopefully only slightly) different, so they must be managed individually, although they are in a series.

How to drive the mosfets, if reference for each is not ground (because they are stacked) and not constant (common mode voltage will reach ~150V for cell 1)?

(incidentally, which mosfets to use, Ids=40A, Vds 3.7V, Vgs~3V?)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFcmRt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You could use a Cascode drive or Opto’s. but I suggest you measure ESR and dV/dt during the tests, then record the results and compare if matched <0.1% or 1% or 10% whatever your acceptance criteria is. Depending of C current ratio

Comment: Not clear how to use cascode drivers in a series of 50.
Optos would draw current from the main branch, right? How to compensate that?

Comment: Opto drivers can be done by 2~3V logic from a uC or DC-DC converter or whatever with 2mA in and 1mA out

Comment: Don't forget the body diode. It is more straightforward to use electromechanical relays for this application.

Comment: of course, but noise (contact clicking) and size become an issue....